# javascript floating bar not getting closed - how to fix this javascript code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, floating

I need some help here. Below is the code in Javascript for a floating sidebar, but I am not able to make it closable or to close it. Can anybody fix the code?

```js
var persistclose = 0 //set to 0 or 1. 1 means once the bar is manually closed, it will remain closed for browser session
var startX = 5 //set x offset of bar in pixels
var startY = 40 //set y offset of bar in pixels
var verticalpos = "fromtop" //enter "fromtop" or "frombottom"

function iecompattest() {
  return (document.compatMode && document.compatMode != "BackCompat") ? document.documentElement : document.body
}

function get_cookie(Name) {
  var search = Name + "="
  var returnvalue = "";
  if (document.cookie.length > 0) {
    offset = document.cookie.indexOf(search)
    if (offset != -1) {
      offset += search.length
      end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", offset);
      if (end == -1) end = document.cookie.length;
      returnvalue = unescape(document.cookie.substring(offset, end))
    }
  }
  return returnvalue;
}

function closebar() {
  if (persistclose)
    document.cookie = "remainclosed=1"
  document.getElementById("topbar").style.visibility = "hidden"
}

function staticbar() {
  barheight = document.getElementById("topbar").offsetHeight
  var ns = (navigator.appName.indexOf("Netscape") != -1) || window.opera;
  var d = document;

  function ml(id) {
    var el = d.getElementById(id);
    if (!persistclose || persistclose && get_cookie("remainclosed") == "")
      el.style.visibility = "visible"
    if (d.layers) el.style = el;
    el.sP = function(x, y) {
      this.style.left = x + "px";
      this.style.top = y + "px";
    };
    el.x = startX;
    if (verticalpos == "fromtop")
      el.y = startY;
    else {
      el.y = ns ? pageYOffset + innerHeight : iecompattest().scrollTop + iecompattest().clientHeight;
      el.y -= startY;
    }
    return el;
  }
  
  window.stayTopLeft = function() {
    if (verticalpos == "fromtop") {
      var pY = ns ? pageYOffset : iecompattest().scrollTop;
      ftlObj.y += (pY + startY - ftlObj.y) / 8;
    } else {
      var pY = ns ? pageYOffset + innerHeight - barheight : iecompattest().scrollTop + iecompattest().clientHeight - barheight;
      ftlObj.y += (pY - startY - ftlObj.y) / 8;
    }
    ftlObj.sP(ftlObj.x, ftlObj.y);
    setTimeout("stayTopLeft()", 10);
  }
  
  ftlObj = ml("topbar");
  stayTopLeft();
}

if (window.addEventListener)
  window.addEventListener("load", staticbar, false)
else if (window.attachEvent)
  window.attachEvent("onload", staticbar)
else if (document.getElementById)
  window.onload = staticbar
```

```css
    #topbar {
      position: absolute;
      border: 0px solid black;
      padding: 1px;
      width: 132px;
      height: 620px;
      visibility: hidden;
      z-index: 100;
    }
```

```html
<div id="topbar">
  <a href="" onClick="closebar(); return false">
    <img src="http://recruitmentapplicationforms.in/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/close.gif" border="0" />
  </a>
  Advertisement
  <ad code goes here>
</div>
```

You can check the code on my site also [recruitment](http://recruitmentapplicationforms.in)

The close button gets disappeared as soon as someone clicks on it, but the floating bar remains live. I want to close the floating bar using that close button, please help me if you know how to do the same.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: *floating bar* Means topbar ?

Comment: you can visit the link for a better idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to remove the `<div id="topbar">...</div>`

If that's the case, adjust this:

```
function closebar() {
  if (persistclose)
    document.cookie = "remainclosed=1"
  document.getElementById("topbar").style.visibility = "hidden"
}
```

to this:

```
function closebar() {
  if (persistclose)
    document.cookie = "remainclosed=1"
  document.getElementById("topbar").remove()
}
```

The function you have in there only sets the visibility to hidden. `remove()` will remove in from the DOM.

Comment: Please mark the answer as selected if it solved your problem